# How to get the Json Value correctly?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am having a `HttpPost` request sending back an object `Value`.

I would like to make the `ComputerLocation` div appear when the object `Value` is true(`s.IsComputer` is a bool).

Currently nothing happens.

I tried to debug it using Firebug and verified that actually the request posts back the object `Value:true`, but when i check my `result.Value`, `Value` is shown as undefined.

Please check what I am doing wrong?

Script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#typeddl').on('change', function () {         
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetItemTypeForm")',
                data: { itemTypeId: $('#typeddl').val() },
                success: function (result) {                            
                        $('#ComputerLocation').toggle(result.Value === true);         
                }
            });
        });
        $('#typeddl').trigger('change');
    });

</script>
```

Json:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult GetItemTypeForm(int itemTypeId)
        {
            //pseudo code
            var data = from s in db.ItemTypes.ToList()
                       where s.ItemTypeId == itemTypeId 
                       select new { Value = s.IsComputer };

            return Json(data);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing a property on the object you pass to `$.ajax`? I think you should use `dataType: "json"` in the request to get a JSON result.

Comment: it seems to send and receive the data fine...  its sends the dropdown id (3) for example and receive back "Value":true for this id which basicaly checks the IsComputer bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `First` method to get single result, because your query returns an `IQueryable<T>`

```
var data = (from s in db.ItemTypes.ToList()
                   where s.ItemTypeId == itemTypeId 
                   select new { Value = s.IsComputer }).First();
```

Then return your result like this:

```
return Json( new { Value = data.Value });
```

Comment: what is the difference with original sample? it also has anonymous object with `Value` property as LINQ query result

Comment: 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  .  I tried just return Json( new { Value = data }); but made no difference

Comment: Because you return list of object, not specific one. And all returned object will be sent to the client. So it will have array of object with property Value

Comment: @Wizeman1986 use .First end of your query. `...select new { Value = s.IsComputer }).First();`

Comment: If you inspect the JSON you would probably see that it looks something like: [{Value: true}]. The [] means that you have an array. You are trying to access the value by doing result.Value, but you can't do that because an array has no property called Value. You either need to access the first item in the array: result[0].Value or like Selman22 said you should modify your query so it doesn't return a collection.